# (SCHEME) convert words-> Numbers

Tags: parsing, numbers, scheme, racket, lexer

I have most of this program down, but I am trying to figure out how to get the grammar done for this program. The program uses a lexer and a parser to turn words into numbers (IE. "million" -> 100000)
I have everything working up to the thousands.

Here is the grammar for the parser

```
  #lang scheme

(S [(zero) $1]
   [(L) $1])
(zero [(ZERO) 0])
**(L [(T) $1]
   [(T D) (expt (thousands-number $1) 10)]
   [(T D L) $1])**
(T [(H) $1]
   [(A HUNDRED H) (+ (* $1 100) $3)]
   [(A HUNDRED) (* $1 100)])
(H [(B) $1]
   [(C) $1]
   [(C B) (+ $1 $2)]) 
(A [(UNDERTEN) (undertwenty-number $1)])
(B [(UNDERTWENTY) (undertwenty-number $1)]
   [(A) $1])
(C [(TENS) (tens-number $1)])
(D [(THOUSANDS) (thousands-number $1)])
)
 )
)
```

I'm trying to use exponents to the power of 10 to get the number. 
Everything else works below 1000. "eight thousand" just returns 8.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code and **Fixed**

```
(S [(zero) $1]
   [(L) $1])
(zero [(ZERO) 0])

   **(L [(T) $1]
     [(T D) (* (expt 10 $2) $1)]
      [(T D L) (+ (* (expt 10 $2) $1) $3) ])**

(T [(H) $1]
   [(A HUNDRED H) (+ (* $1 100) $3)]
   [(A HUNDRED) (* $1 100)])
(H [(B) $1]
   [(C) $1]
   [(C B) (+ $1 $2)]) 
(A [(UNDERTEN) (undertwenty-number $1)])
(B [(UNDERTWENTY) (undertwenty-number $1)]
   [(A) $1])
(C [(TENS) (tens-number $1)])
(D [(THOUSANDS) (thousands-number $1)])
)
 )
   )
```

Will now work for numbers up to a billion.